# Is it "is being build" or "is being built"?

Tags: tenses, passive-voice

> Channel is being **build** with aid of latest technologies available
>   today.

Is the above line correct? or should built be used instead of build? What is the grammatic logic to follow so I understand why particular one is used.

Comment: Aren't channels usually *dug* (not built)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"The channel **is being built** with the aid of the latest technologies available today."

"Is being built," "has been built," "will be built," etc. are all passive forms.  "Build" is active: (a subject) may *build* (an object).

Answer (score 4):

That, I think, depends on whether the sentence was heard or read.

If I **heard** it (without any further context) I would have heard it as

> *Channel is being **billed** with the aid of the latest technologies available today.*

That is, perhaps they're talking about *billing*, and not *building*.

(by the way, the idioms are *with **the** aid of*, and *of **the** latest*; watch those articles, please)

On the other hand, if I **read** it (ditto) I would interpret it as a mistake, since Passive requires the past participle form of the main verb, and *build* is the infinitive, not the past participle.

So either this is a grammar mistake, if they're talking about *building*, or a spelling mistake, if they're talking about *billing*.